# Убираем кнопки telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

from telebot import apihelper


apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://198.50.217.202:1080'}

token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def start(m):
    # print(m)
    hellomsg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Здравствуй, {}!'.format(m.chat.first_name))

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(sport) for sport in ['Футбол', 'Хоккей']])

    sports = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Выбирите вид спорта!", reply_markup = keyboard)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(sports, FunctionSports)

def FunctionSports(m):
    if m.text == 'Футбол':
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Ты выбрал футбол", parse_mode = 'Markdown')
    elif m.text == 'Хоккей':
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Ты выбрал хоккей", parse_mode = 'Markdown')


bot.polling()
```

Надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Футбол" кнопки убирались

Comment: Прочтение этого документа ясности не вносит? https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для полного удаления кнопок (не скрытие) используйте `types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()`:

```
if m.text == 'Футбол':
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Ты выбрал футбол", reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(), parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Answer (score 0):

`keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)` используй `True`,

```
True keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
```

Comment: Могли бы Вы дать пояснения к своему ответу? Ведь строка `keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)` имеется в коде автора вопроса. Спасибо.